# Silverlight 4.0 IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

How to view all the content in my IsolatedStorageFile by setting a new page in your browser?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what "setting a new page in your browser" has to do with it.  I assume you are refering perhaps to the loading of a different Silverlight app from the site.

There are two Isolated Stores one per application and one per site.  If you do mean moving from one app to another then you will only be able to share the site store between them.

You can get access to the site store with `IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForSite()`.

Enumeration of Directories and Files in the store are preformed with the methods `GetDirectories()` and `GetFiles()`.  Try having a read through the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(v=VS.96).aspx).